# Parser fail to read html content using ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to parse some html content using ruby. I use the following code:

```
require 'open-uri'


url = 'http://www.fooducate.com/appo#!page=browse&nav=0'
html = open(url)
IO.copy_stream(html,'test.html')
```

But what i have get is only the content div without content:

```
<div id="page-content" class="content group">
</div>
```

Is that a bug in parser? How can i fix that problem ?

Comment: Note that you're not actually using a html parser. You're just downloading an IO stream via HTTP - `IO.copy_stream` does not care about the content. A parser would be something like Nokogiri which reads the HTML document and builds a representation of it so you can read or manipulate the document.

Comment: I have already tried to use Nokogiri to get content, but i get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the comment just above that div, you'll see the rest of the content is loaded via JavaScript. To retrieve it, you'd need to run the page's scripts like a browser would, or otherwise emulate the second fetch.

```
<!-- hook for any page content - JS Navigation object expects that -->
<div id="page-content" class="content group">
</div>
```

This behavior is visible when you load the page through your browser. Notice that the navigation and layout load, but you see a "Loading" message for a few seconds before the content fills in.

Comment: What do you recommend to have the browser result ? or How can i do a second fetch ?

Comment: You could try something like [ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) to run the JavaScript. Or it looks like the data comes from http://www.fooducate.com/internal/chef_client_proxy/get_browse_tree if you want to start with JSON instead.